# reduce function to count words and add them together to 1 number /doesnt work

Tags: javascript, loops, dictionary, reduce

I have some code (already provided and need to add code to it so it works. All the functions below must stay (its just the exercise) and the last function (reduce function) pass 2 tests:

```
reduce([3, 5, 7], 0, adding); // works

reduce(["hey whats up", "this is a test"], 0, countingWords); // doesn not work
```

I believe the countingWords  must be changed so the reduce function works for both cases

```
var adding = function(a, b) { //this function was provided
  return a + b;
};

function counting(string){ //this function must stay too
  var words;

  if (typeof string==='string') {
    words=string.split(" ");
  }
  else {
    words=string.join(" ").split(" ");
  }

  return words.length;
}

//counting("this is a sentence"); // should return 4 and it does -all good

function countingWords(words) { //must stay
  return counting(words);
}

function reduce(array,initial,func){
  var current=initial;
  for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    current=func(current,array[i]);
  }
  return current;
}

reduce([3, 5, 7], 0, adding); // works

reduce(["hey whats up", "this is a test"], 0, counting); // doesn not work
```

Greatful for help or suggestions on what to change!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using reduce function does work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37284977/using-reduce-function-does-work)

Comment: First, you need to describe what exactly doesn't work. What is it doing vs what you want it to do. And, just like your previous question, you aren't keeping a running sum with that function. You need to keep track of the total accumulated value **and** the value from the current function.

Comment: I said it: reduce([3, 5, 7], 0, adding); // works

reduce(["hey whats up", "this is a test"], 0, countingWords); // doesn not work and the reduce function must work for both cases (not just 1)-I think I have to change the countingWords but don't know how to

Comment: Do you notice anything different between your `adding` function and your `countingWords` function? Something about how many parameters they take... What do you think the first parameter in `adding` is?

Comment: the first one is the "current" - I actually tried changing the reduce function to current+=func(array[i]); and then reduce(["hey whats up", "this is a test"], 0, countingWords); seemed to be working, but then reduce([3, 5, 7], 0, adding);  stopped working-thats why I thought I don't have to change the reduce function BUT the coundWords function

Comment: That's because you're changing the wrong things! If `adding`, the function you're passing to `reduce` takes two arguments then shouldn't `counting` take two arguments too?

Comment: Oh wait I see what you are saying, I think :) I tried to change it to function countingWords(words, word) {
 return counting(words+ word);
} but that doesn't seem right as I get the error fun is not a function

Comment: Try `return words + counting(word)`.

Comment: Can you modify the `countingWords` function?

Comment: Mike- thank you it works now!